# How to group by and calculate sum in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am stuck at below point not getting how do I get expected output

I have used pandas to read json data

**code :**

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.read_json('/content/sample_data/abc.json')
mycolumns = ['A','B']
dt[mycolumns ]
```

Below is the following data I have read it using pandas :

```
0   {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z'}   {'$date': '2020-12-02T13:32:57.781Z'}
1   {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z'}   {'$date': '2020-12-02T13:32:59.955Z'}
2   {'$date': '2020-12-04T12:33:13.686Z'}   {'$date': '2020-12-04T14:33:13.686Z'}
3   {'$date': '2020-12-04T12:33:16.199Z'}   {'$date': '2020-12-04T14:33:16.199Z'}
```

Now I need to do group by on date : `YYY-MM-DD` and calculate difference of time in hours  and do sum on it

Trying to get into below format so that I can do some difference of A - B

**Note :** I have given dummy difference just for reference not able to identify how to implement

```
    DATE         A                                     B                 Difference         
0   2020-12-02  '2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z'  '2020-12-02T13:32:57.781Z'      3              
1   2020-12-02  '2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z'  '2020-12-02T13:32:59.955Z'      4    
2   2020-12-04  '2020-12-02T13:33:13.686Z'  '2020-12-04T14:33:13.686Z'      2
3   2020-12-04  '2020-12-02T13:33:16.199Z'  '2020-12-04T14:33:13.686Z'      1
```

**MY expected output**

```
    DATE          Sum        
0   2020-12-02     7              
1   2020-12-04     3
```

I am providing data in csv format just use it

```
0,{'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z'},{'$date': '2020-12-02T13:32:57.781Z'}
1,{'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z'},{'$date': '2020-12-02T13:32:59.955Z'}
2,{'$date': '2020-12-04T12:33:13.686Z'},{'$date': '2020-12-04T14:33:13.686Z'}
3,{'$date': '2020-12-04T12:33:16.199Z'},{'$date': '2020-12-04T14:33:13.686Z'}
```

**Please find data in dict format**

```
{'__v': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 '_id': {0: {'$oid': '5fc7897969b8ab14e1cad8f4'},
  1: {'$oid': '5fc7897b69b8ab14e1cad8f5'},
  2: {'$oid': '5fc7898969b8ab14e1cad8fa'},
  3: {'$oid': '5fc7898c69b8ab14e1cad8fb'},
  4: {'$oid': '5fca09bb45db2d39eee040b2'}},
 'createdAt': {0: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z'},
  1: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z'},
  2: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:33:13.686Z'},
  3: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:33:16.199Z'},
  4: {'$date': '2020-12-04T10:04:43.662Z'}},
 'dId': {0: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45'},
  1: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45'},
  2: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45'},
  3: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45'},
  4: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45'}},
 'm': {0: '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
  1: '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
  2: '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
  3: '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
  4: '24:6F:28:55:7C:55'},
 'pId': {0: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'},
  1: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'},
  2: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'},
  3: {'$oid': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'},
  4: {'$oid': '5fc9f66cf7fa2b262ecb6c5a'}},
 'pVal': {0: {'__v': 0,
   '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46',
   'cat': 's',
   'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.237Z',
   'device': {'__v': 0,
    '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45',
    'assignedTo': '5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d',
    'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z',
    'dType': '5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb',
    'deviceId': 'LTAC21220050009',
    'macId': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
    'ports': ['5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'],
    'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:36.773Z'},
   'mac': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
   'no': '0',
   'portIcon': 'AC',
   'portType': 'AC',
   'status': None,
   'title': 'Switch',
   'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:57.776Z',
   'val': 1},
  1: {'__v': 0,
   '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46',
   'cat': 's',
   'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.237Z',
   'device': {'__v': 0,
    '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45',
    'assignedTo': '5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d',
    'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z',
    'dType': '5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb',
    'deviceId': 'LTAC21220050009',
    'macId': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
    'ports': ['5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'],
    'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:36.773Z'},
   'mac': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
   'no': '0',
   'portIcon': 'AC',
   'portType': 'AC',
   'status': None,
   'title': 'Switch',
   'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:59.951Z',
   'val': 0},
  2: {'__v': 0,
   '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46',
   'cat': 's',
   'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.237Z',
   'device': {'__v': 0,
    '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45',
    'assignedTo': '5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d',
    'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z',
    'dType': '5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb',
    'deviceId': 'LTAC21220050009',
    'macId': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
    'ports': ['5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'],
    'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:36.773Z'},
   'mac': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
   'no': '0',
   'portIcon': 'AC',
   'portType': 'AC',
   'status': None,
   'title': 'Switch',
   'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:33:13.682Z',
   'val': 1},
  3: {'__v': 0,
   '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46',
   'cat': 's',
   'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.237Z',
   'device': {'__v': 0,
    '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45',
    'assignedTo': '5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d',
    'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z',
    'dType': '5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb',
    'deviceId': 'LTAC21220050009',
    'macId': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
    'ports': ['5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46'],
    'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:36.773Z'},
   'mac': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
   'no': '0',
   'portIcon': 'AC',
   'portType': 'AC',
   'status': None,
   'title': 'Switch',
   'updatedAt': '2020-12-02T12:33:16.195Z',
   'val': 0},
  4: {'__v': 0,
   '_id': '5fc9f66cf7fa2b262ecb6c5a',
   'cat': 's',
   'createdAt': '2020-12-04T08:42:20.724Z',
   'device': {'__v': 2,
    '_id': '5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45',
    'assignedTo': '5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d',
    'configured': True,
    'createdAt': '2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z',
    'dType': '5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb',
    'deviceId': 'LTSAC21220050009',
    'lastConfiguredAt': '2020-12-04T10:04:15.000Z',
    'lp': '2020-12-04T10:04:31.482Z',
    'macId': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
    'ns': '-69',
    'online': True,
    'ports': ['5fc9f66cf7fa2b262ecb6c5a'],
    'updatedAt': '2020-12-04T10:04:31.483Z',
    'version': 'AC_1.5'},
   'mac': '24:6F:28:55:7C:55',
   'no': '0',
   'portIcon': 'AC',
   'portType': 'AC',
   'status': None,
   'title': 'Switch',
   'updatedAt': '2020-12-04T10:04:43.657Z',
   'val': 1}},
 't': {0: 'o', 1: 'o', 2: 'o', 3: 'o', 4: 'o'},
 'updatedAt': {0: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z'},
  1: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z'},
  2: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:33:13.686Z'},
  3: {'$date': '2020-12-02T12:33:16.199Z'},
  4: {'$date': '2020-12-04T10:04:43.662Z'}}}
```

Comment: Please provide a constructor for your DataFrame. `dt.head().to_dict()`

Comment: @not_speshal  : I am new to pandas no idea about constructor. it would be great if you could copy paste the data and create csv file and read it using pandas and perform logic on it

Comment: @not_speshal : typo error let me change

Comment: `read_json` doesn't work with the sample CSV you've provided. Either provide a valid json or provide a sample of your DataFrame using `dt.head().to_dict()`.

Comment: @not_speshal : i have provided data in dict format please check the question again . incase you find similar timestample just update some record and build logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the difference in hours between the "updatedAt" and "createdAt" columns:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(dt["pVal"])
df["createdAt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["createdAt"])
df["updatedAt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["updatedAt"])
df["Difference"] = df["updatedAt"].sub(df["createdAt"]).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
output = df.groupby(df["createdAt"].dt.date)["Difference"].sum().reset_index()

>>> output
    createdAt  Difference
0  2020-12-02    0.057404
1  2020-12-04    1.373037
```

Comment: : Can you please display  `val` column also in your output ... please need group by on `val and createdAt`